# setting fish for web browser instead of text editor

Tags: config, fish

When running `fish_config`, it starts the configuration with `Web config started at 'file:///home/akwXXXX/.cache/fish/web_config-K1L2BW.html'. Hit enter to stop.`

Yet, instead of opening the web browser, it starts the code editor I have.

What should I do to use my default web browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fish_config` is a python script that uses python's [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), which respects the $BROWSER variable.

So set $BROWSER, e.g. via `set -gx BROWSER /path/to/browser` in your config.fish.